# Retrieving data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from table employee. but two fields are not coming in   the table instead array is coming .How to fix it??
I am trying to retrieve data from table employee. but two fields are not coming in the table instead array is coming .How to fix it??

```
 <?php
 include('dbconnect.php');
 ?>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<?php
$query=("Select * from employee");
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>

<table border=2px solid gray >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Employee Id</th>
<th>Employee Name</th>
<th>Employee DOB</th>
<th>Employee Addr</th>
<th>Employee Dept</th>
<th> Employee Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td>{$row['emp_id']}</td>
<td>{$row['emp_name']}</td>
<td>{$row['emp_dob']}</td>
<td>{$row['emp_addr']}</td>
<td>$row{['emp_dept']}</td>
<td>$row{['emp_salary']} </td>
</tr>" ;
}

?>

</tbody>


</table>
<?php mysql_close($link); ?>







</body>
</html>

output:



1   farook  31-08-1981  Chittagong  Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
2   harun   30-08-1981  Chittagong  Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
3   Kamrul  30-08-1982  Barisal     Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
4   Qamrul  01-08-1980  Chittagong  Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
5   Zillul  30-07-1980  Kutubdia    Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
6   Abdullah Al Amin    25-05-1978  Chittagong  Array{['emp_dept']}     Array{['emp_salary']}
```

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error ...replace

```
<td>$row{['emp_dept']}</td>
<td>$row{['emp_salary']} </td>
```

with

```
<td>{$row['emp_dept']}</td>
<td>{$row['emp_salary']} </td>
```